# Credibility of data when getting time out error in an update

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, error, automationstudio, timeout

If my query is updating a data extension and gives a time out error, does the destination data extension suffer any changes to its data or is it exactly the same as before running the activity?

Thanks.

Comment: Write is not committed if it is not successful and changes are rolled back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Journey Specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getting-started-spec.htm) states that:

> Guarantees that all changes to a journey are atomic, preventing partial data corruption.

This means that either all changes are applied, or none. If the update times out, all changes will be discarded, as if nothing ever happened. In the event of an error, the Data Extension will be in the exact state as before running the Journey.